# openId-client is failed to minify for react application

Tags: reactjs, openid-connect

I have created react application authentication using openid-client-2.2.1 when I'm trying to minify the application it is throwing   error
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the code from this file:

```
    ./node_modules/openid-client/lib/open_id_connect_error.js:3
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your react scripts to version 2.1.1.